# Usage of keyword const in a function argument

Tags: c

Taking the following example:

```
void foo(const int foobar);
```

Is the keyword `const` meaningful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, obviously. Your function `foo()` will not be able to modify the value `foobar` inside the function.

Comment: Hi Sourav; hope you're fine. "will not be able"... This is wrong. In C, `const` is a promise by the programmer not to change, not enforced by the compiler/runtime.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, but attempting so will generate comp-err, right?

Comment: You can cast away the const, still using the same object (yes, that should generate a warning, but, hey warning is better than error ...;-)

Comment: Same here. Still busy.

Comment: @Olaf ahh, that way, it's _bypassed_. At least, for the first time, without the cast, we'll get to know, we should not have changed that....... :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a destructive bastard;-) - one reason I have to be careful writing code, if I'm not, it breaks when I test already. Other people manage to surf around their bugs (unintended). FYI: In other languages, like Python, you can make objects true read-only using e.g. properties. Any access will result in runtime exception. In C, there is no guarantee about this, just UB.

Comment: @Olaf Can't agree more to the later part of the comment sir . :-)

Comment: Pew, I was already wondering what part the +1 was for ;-)

Comment: @Olaf That's why I explained. ;-)

Comment: I guess the larger question is 'who would care?'. The parameter is a value copy anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames maybe the developer would, who doesn't want the maintainer to _alter_ the input parameter, for _some_ reason. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh sure, yes.  It's just that I'm struggling to think of an example here I may want to do that:)